# Vue: Initial checkbox state from data store

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I call an api that gathers a JSON object. Inside that object I get values like this:

```
extensionStore:Object
    currentExtension:Object
        callForward:Object
            destination:"123456"
            voicemail:"false"
        directoryNumber:"2001"
        id:"c494b26f-0f3b-f71d-379e-5a79ce96cf85"
        routePartition:"LOC1_Internal_RPT"
```

Then I do a check like this:

```
    if (!destination == null) {
        "destination" is checked}
   else if (voicemail == true) {
        "voicemail" is checked}
   else { checked == false }
```

My store:

```
const state = {
  extensionList: {},
  currentExtension: null,
}

const getters = {
  hasVoicemail: state => {
    Boolean(state.currentExtension.callForward.voicemail)
  },
  hasDestination: state => {
    Boolean(state.currentExtension.callForward.destination)
  },
  extensionId: state => {
    return state.currentExtension.callForward.currentExtension.id
  }
}

const mutations = {
  SET_EXTENSION_LIST (state, extensionList) {
    state.extensionList = extensionList
  },
  SET_CURRENT_EXTENSION (state, currentExtension) {
    state.currentExtension = currentExtension
  }
}

const actions = {
  setExtensionList: ({commit}, extensionList) => {
    const authUser = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
    let authData = authUser.user
    return Vue.http.get(extensionsUrl + authData, {headers: getHeader()})
      .then(response => {
        commit('SET_EXTENSION_LIST', response.data)
    })
  },
  setCurrentExtension: ({commit}, currentExtension) => {
    commit('SET_CURRENT_EXTENSION', currentExtension)
  }
}
```

Attempt to use the data here in currentExtension.vue

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="handleExtensionFormSubmit()">
  <h4>Currently Editing Line: {{extensionStore.currentExtension.directoryNumber}}</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked"/>
  <label for="click_me">Forward All Calls to:</label>
  <input type="radio" id="one" value="Voicemail" v-bind:disabled="!checked" v-model="checkedValue">
  <label for="one">Voicemail</label>
  <input type="radio" id="two" value="Destination" v-bind:disabled="!checked" v-model="checkedValue">
  <label for="two">Destination</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="destinationNumber" v-bind:disabled="!checked">
  <button class="button" type="submit" name="button" v-bind:disabled="!checked">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My data object is here:

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
import {callForwardUrl, getHeader} from './../../config'
export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapState ({
        extensionStore: state => state.extensionStore
      })
    },
    data () {
      return {
          checked: '',
          checkedValue: '',
          destinationNumber: ''
      }
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mam6sq9c/

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the value from my request inside the checkboxes and radio. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) or [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) to select the pieces of data that you want from the store and map them to computed properties on your component. You can then bind the computed properties to the inputs in your component.

Comment: Edited my post: I do use that, but I'm unclear how to map them.

Comment: What does your state tree look like? I'm assuming the `callForward` object sits inside of `extensionStore`.

Comment: I edited my post for readability: extensionStore > currentExtension > callForward > destination&&voicemail

Comment: You could write getters called: `hasDestination`, `hasVoicemail`. Each getter would look something like this (example for `hasDestination`): `state => Boolean(state.extensionStore.currentExtension.callForward.destination)`. You can then use `mapGetters` to map that to your component. And after that bind `hasDestination` to the relevant input.

Comment: Last question for you. Edited my post to reflect where I'm at. However, my getter is trying to get information from my store before it's available. 
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'voicemail' of undefined at hasVoicemail' The currentExtension state becomes available when the user selects from a list.

Comment: You can initialise your state tree with empty or null values (set `extensionStore.currentExtension.callForward.destination` to `null`). Although I would also recommend that shallower state trees are better as they will simplify data models possibly resulting in more accurate and concise modelling as well as give a better developer experience.